# "Error 87 the all option is not recognised in this context" using DISM to enable IIS

Tags: iis, batch-file, dism

I am trying to use a bat to enable IIS to run an asp.net application on a windows 7 (professional) 64bit machine and seem to be constantly encountering this issue. I am running the bat file as an administrator. The entry in my bat file I am using is as follows:

```
%systemroot%\sysnative\dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

According to the documentation I have read the all switch should enable all parent features needed to needed to run ASP.net 4.5. I've also tried using just `IIS-ASPNET` and `IIS-ASPNET40` all received the same error.

```
Error 87 the all option is not recognised in this context
```

I originally tried to do each feature needed to run my application individually but encountered similar issues.

Answer (score 9):

You have 2 problems. The first is that the `/all` flag was introduced in `Windows 8`, and so nonexistent in `Windows 7`. The second is that the `IIS-ASPNET45` feature also isn't a part of `Windows 7`, because `.Net 4.5` came out after it did.

What you need to do is:

- Enable the specific features you need for `IIS` explicitly using `DISM`:

```
dism.exe /NoRestart /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole
```

- Register `ASP.Net 4.5` (assuming `.Net 4.5` is already installed):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe /i
```

Answer (score 0):

#### ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

87 (0x57)
The parameter is incorrect.

#### The `/all` flag is not recognized as a valid parameter.

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET /all
```

**[DISM @ MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx)**

See [l3arnon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047813/891976).

Comment: The order is irrelevant. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25047813/885318